# subfigure numbering parentheses flipped with babel + right-to-left language + subfig

Tags: captions, subfloats, babel, hebrew, right-to-left

Eyal's babel incompatibility of the week... this time a question due to H.R. on the IVRITEX mailing list.

The [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel/) is incompatible with the [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig/) package. If you add a subfig with a caption:

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{subfig}


\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}[tbph]
      \subfloat[\L{A sub-figure}]{\L{The subfigure}}
      \caption{\L{A figure caption}}
   \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The sub-figure is numbered; the numbering uses Hebrew letters (Aleph, Bet, Gimel; in this case, Aleph - א). The numbering is enclosed in parentheses, but due to direction issues, the parentheses are in the opposite directions of where they should be:

[image: rendering]

Is there a workaround for this problem? A minimal workaround with no additional package dependencies is preferred.

Note: You don't see this problem with Arabic instead of Hebrew (and the \L's removed) since when it's Arabic, you get a left-to-right float and Latin enumeration. Maybe it manifests in some other way with Arabic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H.R.'s own workaround uses the `caption` package: He replaces

```
\usepackage{subfig}
```

with

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{hebparens}{)#2(}
\usepackage[labelformat=hebparens,labelsep=space]{subfig}
```

which resolves the issue; apparently subfig loads caption anyway, so, I guess this solves it.

Comment: Since this does not seem to represent an answer, you should include it in your original post.

Comment: @Werner: Tweaked the question, now this is a bona fide, though sub-optimal, answer :-)

Comment: @einpoklum You say this is not what you are looking for, so it still seems to be part of the question rather than an answer.

Comment: @JosephWright: I no longer say that... I should have been more exact in phrasing the question. The problem is the flipping. The solution with `caption` does solve the problem, but I would prefer another solution - just like you might with any other question on TeX.SX which has some solution provided...

Comment: [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) uses [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) as part of the package. So, using a solution that "loads `caption`" is perfectly fine. Do you *still* require a solution that doesn't load `caption` verbatim?

Comment: Just use `\usepackage{subfig}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{hebparens}{)#2(}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=hebparens,labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=hebparens,labelsep=space}`; you don't need to load [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) explicitly.